# Winforms control sometimes rendered blank

Tags: c#, winforms, window-handles

I'm keep getting the feedback that one WinForms control is rendered as blank (no window title, no button text, etc.) as can be seen in the screenshot below. This is a rare issue that seems to happen only after the application runs for a very long time. I am not even able to reproduce it so I assume the UI code is not the problem hence I don't post it here.

I'm wondering if this has to do with windows running out of window handles, or something else? Any advices why this could happen?

[image: Blank WinForms control]

Comment: Diagnose with Task Manager, Processes tab.  Add the Handles, User Objects and GDI Objects columns.  Observe while exercising the UI, a steadily increasing number spells long-term doom.  Probably the latter.  Best if done by using the same Windows version as the user uses, Win10 got to be pretty forgiving.  Fix with calling Dispose() or using *using* where needed.  Or GC.Collect in a timer callback if you're truly desperate.

Comment: Are you creating graphic objects from Resources (e.g., that question mark)? Are you rendering graphic objects in a `Paint` handler? Bitmaps, Pens, Brushes, Fonts, GraphicsPath objects, StringFormat objects etc. need to be disposed. If you get an Image from the Resources, assign that object to an Image / Bitmap Field, dispose of it when the Form closes. Don't assign an Image property directly from `Properties.Resources`. -- Don't use `[Controls].Remove()` or `[Controls].Clear()`, dispose of the objects in the collection instead.